# Azure Portal - possible to set tile to run directly runbook/webjob/webhook/scheduler job?

Tags: azure, azureportal

I would like to run A, B, C, D as follows from Dashboard directly. The A is available as the attached image. Do you know if available as for B, C and D?

- Automation Account

  - Runbook A (ex. restarts the specified App Service)
- App Service

  - Webjob B (ex. restarts the App Service)
  - Webhook C for running Webjob B(URL, username, password)
- Scheduler Job Collection

  - Scheduler Job D ( ex. checks the specifed endpoint status)

[image: Tile to run Runbook A]

Comment: none of this is possible, also, what do you mean saying A is possible, it would just redirect you to runbook blade

Comment: @4c74356b41 Thanks, I mean that redirection equal to "possible." I couldn't find how to add tiles for B, C and D as same way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your best bet is to go to the resource in question, and click the PIN button, if those have separate blades, you can do that, if they don't - you cant. It will pin the resource blade.

Otherwise you can't do that.